# Practical parameter file reading in java

Tags: java, file-io, parameters

I am starting with java and I am wondering which (text) file format I should use to read some parameter sets, such as:

```
Item1:   // the item name is not important
  - filename: item1.txt
  - contentType: individual
  - ...

Item2:
  - filename: item2.txt
  - contentType: group
  - ...

...
```

The purpose is to give a list of files to be loaded into a DB, as well as some description of file content.

So my question is:

- What practical parameter file format should I use?

And by practical I mean:

1. no (additional) external libraries required, so typically "standard" java and spring (the framework used)
2. low development cost: easy parsing of the loaded file content, such as:

`List<Header> headers = read_file(headerFileName);
for(Header header : headers){
    MyTable table = new MyTable(header.contentType);
    table.loadFromFile(header.filename);
}`

3. file format readability (yaml'd be nice, but it seems to require an external lib)

Note: this question is similar to [What is the best practice for reading property files in Java EE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/883858/1206998), but I don't know much about the java ecosystem so I cannot be sure (eg. I understood that spring is an alternative to JavaEE). Here I tried to be more precise on my needs, and in particular on the "shape" of the parameters.

Comment: XML or JSON. I think Spring uses Jackson. You also have SAX/StaX/DOM in-house.

Comment: I see votes on closing the question as "to broad". I expected duplicate or maybe opinion-based, but not this reason because I actually fill my question is quite precise. Could anyone explain why it would be too broad? Basically I hope for answers to state one (or 2) way(s) to answer my requirement, if possible with some positionning w.r.t the "practical" points I listed. A real plus would be an example parameter file to evaluate point 3, and/or a little code example to evaluate point 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using XML files and using [JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXB.html) to load them.

Why? Because of the following pros:

- Because it is awefully simple.
- No external libraries are needed.
- The config file is well readable (simple XML), it can be edited with any text editors or advanced XML editors.
- It is flexible enough to add other data later on to the parameters.
- Also very easy to modify/save parameters from code at runtime (see at the end).
- Thanks to XML you don't have to worry about character encoding (like in case of properties files).

**Modelling:**

First you need to create classes to "model" your parameters:

```
class Parameters {
    @XmlElement(name = "item")
    public List<Item> items;
}

class Item {
    public String fileName;
    public String contentType;
}
```

**Example input XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<parameters>
    <item>
        <fileName>item1.txt</fileName>
        <contentType>individual</contentType>
    </item>
    <item>
        <fileName>item2.txt</fileName>
        <contentType>group</contentType>
    </item>
</parameters>
```

**Loading the parameters**

And this is how you can load it, it's only 1 method call:

```
Parameters p = JAXB.unmarshal(new File("params.xml"), Parameters.class);

for (Item item : p.items)
    System.out.println(item.fileName + ": " + item.contentType);
```

**Output:**

```
item1.txt: individual
item2.txt: group
```

### Alternative (simplified) XML input

To make the input XML file shorter, more easily readable, we can make the following change:

```
class Item {
    @XmlAttribute
    public String fileName;
    @XmlAttribute
    public String contentType;
}
```

Here we basically specified to store/read the data of an `Item` as XML attributes and not as child elements. With this modification the input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<parameters>
    <item fileName="item1.txt" contentType="individual" />
    <item fileName="item2.txt" contentType="group" />
</parameters>
```

### Modifying and Saving parameters at runtime

If we want to modify the parameters and save them at runtime, it is just as easy as loading them: one line only. Below I modify the first item, and I also create and add a new third item:

```
// Modify item #1
p.items.get(0).fileName = "item11.txt";
p.items.get(0).contentType = "short";

// Create and add a new item
Item item3 = new Item();
item3.fileName = "item3.txt";
item3.contentType = "newtype";
p.items.add(item3);

// Save the modified parameters: 1 line:
JAXB.marshal(p, new File("params-out.xml"));
```

**Output of the modified parameters:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<parameters>
    <item fileName="item11.txt" contentType="short"/>
    <item fileName="item2.txt" contentType="group"/>
    <item fileName="item3.txt" contentType="newtype"/>
</parameters>
```

Comment: I couldn't ask for more, thanks! Just one question, I guess the attributes in the class and xml file should exactly match. I can work with that, but just in case: what happens if there are missing or undeclared attributes in the file?

Comment: If names do not match, the Java fields will remain `null`. The `JAXB` class tries to parse and convert XML to Java as much as possible. Check the Javadoc, there are many options (e.g. `JAXBContext`, `Unmarshaller`, `Marshaller`), what I included is just an example for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

### Spring boot

I asked that question long time ago, when starting with spring and (properly with) java. But I do now hav a proper answer:

When using Spring, it is customary to use one if the externalized configuration tools of spring-boot (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). Spring-boot will read all .properties and/or .yml resources files. And use its content to fill java properties. There is two methods to access those:

- using `@Value` on a property of inside a `@Component` class. it's the easiest method, but I don't recommend it as it is very difficult to track which properties are required for a project
- Using `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my-project")` decorated class and spring boot will fill up the class fields accordingly

---

### Typesafe config

I'd like to add the for non-spring project, or even with those, I recommend to use the very practical and lightweight typesafe config lib: https://github.com/lightbend/config

Same principle in practice, but without the Spring hidden/IoC system. Add property files in your resource (or jvm start config) and access it using typesafe config tool.